# Why am I getting columns instead of rows in CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have an html page with 1 row for nav and 1 row for body. I have specified the two rows using `css-grid`. I have named the different grid areas

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start]40px [nav-row-end] [body-row-start] auto [body-row-end];
}

.my-border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.my-nav-height {
  height: 40px;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}

#nav {
  grid-row: nav-row-start/nav-row-end;
}

#body {
  grid-row: body-row-start/body-row-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="nav" class="my-border my-nav-height">nav bar</div>
  <div id="body" class="my-border my-body-height">body</div>
</div>
```

I see this (2 columns instead of two rows)

[image]

But if I add `0px` dimension for gutter then I see two rows

[image]

Is gutter dimension mandatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple syntax error.

You can't place two [author-defined identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#named-lines) consecutively. They need to be combined.

This is wrong:

```
grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start] 40px [nav-row-end] [body-row-start] auto [body-row-end]
```

This is right:

```
grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start] 40px [nav-row-end body-row-start] auto [body-row-end]
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start] 40px [nav-row-end body-row-start] auto [body-row-end];
}

.my-border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.my-nav-height {}

div {
  height: 100vh;
}

#nav {
  grid-row: nav-row-start/nav-row-end;
}

#body {
  grid-row: body-row-start/body-row-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="nav" class="my-border my-nav-height">nav bar</div>
  <div id="body" class="my-border my-body-height">body</div>
</div>
```

(Using the `grid-gap` property, I couldn't reproduce the gutter problem you encountered.)